Error: "D:\System Volume Information" when building with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA
I'm encountering an 'Access Denied: D:\System Volume Information' error when building my Minecraft Paper plugin Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA. Strangely, the same project works perfectly in a VM environment using the same IntelliJ version and plugins. I've already reached out to support but found no solution.
I tried invalidating caches, reinstalling IntelliJ and Windows, checking Gradle version, and even buying a new PC. Buying a new PC temporarily resolved the issue, but it has now returned. Also using another IDE like Eclipse fixes the issue too. Expected project to load, but got "D:\System Volume Information" error instead.
Error when Building:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\System Volume Information
> D:\System Volume Information

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 498ms

IDEA logs: https://pastebin.com/pmHLkiGx

My best guess would be, that the ! in the IDE path is the problem. If this is the case, you should probably report an issue to JetBrains. But there could be quite some tools that do not cope well with ! in paths anyway.

Reinstalling the jre and jdk to the default path fixed the error for me.

Issue was resolved by installing both IDEA and JDK to their default locations.
(Originally were both were installed on the D drive).
